# How a non root user can add users in linux

Tags: linux, docker, podman

I am trying to launch a container on Centos 8 / RH 8 as a non root user and simultaneously I want to create on the fly a user dynamically to the container.

I am using the entrypoint script to do that sample below:

```
$ cat docker-entrypoint.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [[ "$(id -u)" -eq "0" ]] && [[ -n "${UID_ENV}" ]] && [[ -n "${USERNAME_ENV}" ]]
then
        if [[ -z "$(getent passwd ${UID_ENV})" ]] && [[ -z "$(getent passwd ${USERNAME_ENV})" ]] && [[ -z "$(getent group ${UID_ENV})" ]]
        then
                groupadd -g ${GID_ENV} -r ${USERNAME_ENV} && \
                        useradd -rm -u ${UID_ENV} -g ${GID_ENV} ${USERNAME_ENV}
        else
                echo "User: $(getent passwd "${UID_ENV}" | cut -d: -f1) with uid: ${UID_ENV} already exists"
        fi

        if [[ -n "${VOLUMES_ENV})" ]]
        then
                for vol in ${VOLUMES_ENV}
                do
                        echo "Chown Directory: ${vol} with parameters: ${UID_ENV}:${GID_ENV}"
                        chown -R ${UID_ENV}:${GID_ENV} ${vol}
                done
        fi
        exec su-exec "${USERNAME_ENV}" "$@"
else
        if ! [[ `whoami 2>/dev/null` ]]
        then
                echo "Do not use the 'docker run -u ...' on this image!"
                exit 1
        fi
        exec "$@"
fi
```

On the Dockerfile you can define the parameters e.g.:

```
ENV FROM centos:7

ENV=${UID_ENV:-"12345"}
ENV GID_ENV=${GID_ENV:-"12345"}
ENV VOLUMES_ENV=""
ENV USERNAME_ENV=${USERNAME_ENV:-"test-user"}

COPY ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "/usr/local/bin/"]

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Then as a second step you can build the container with podman (no need to pass parameters it will use the default ones):

```
podman build --rm -t local/c7-ssample . && podman run --name centos-test --rm -it local/c7-ssample
```

This works perfectly for Centos 7 / RH 7 because docker daemon is running under root.

The problem occurs when on the new OS Centos 8 / RH 8 the user wants to use podman which runs as a non root user.

The error (which makes sense) that I am getting when I running the image:

```
groupadd: /etc/group.11: lock file already used
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
```

Any idea how to give authorization to user to be able to add users as a non root user?

**Update:**

Possible workaround (not desired) is to pass the `--build-arg` as a parameter during build time. Sample of code / configurations:

```
ENV FROM centos:7

ARG ARG_UID=${ARG_UID:-"12345"}
ARG ARG_GID=${ARG_GID:-$ARG_UID}
ARG ARG_VOLUMES=""
ARG ARG_USERNAME=${ARG_USERNAME:-"test-user"}

ENV UID_ENV=${ARG_UID}
ENV GID_ENV=${ARG_GID}
ENV VOLUMES_ENV=${ARG_VOLUMES}
ENV USERNAME_ENV=${ARG_USERNAME}

COPY ["docker-entrypoint.sh", "/usr/local/bin/"]

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Then during build time you need to pass the parameter(s) if you decide to overide:

```
podman build --rm --build-arg ARG_UID=54321 -t local/c7-ssample . && podman run --name centos-test --rm -it local/c7-ssample
```

But possibly the solution is included in RH 8.2 as [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) pointed out.

I need to pull test and I will update later on.

Comment: I am confused. Is the problem running docker as non-root, or adding a user as non-root?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor the problem is when I am running a container and this container needs to add the user. Since I am launching the container as a non root user it gives me the error that the group file is locked. I assume if the (non root) user had the authorization to add users this problem would be resolved (I think).

Comment: Is this container, not a container, but instead an emulation of a container.

Comment: Why not put it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The simplest approach is to add it on the Dockerfile like adduser etc etc...On this case I bind my self to use a user that can not be updated on the fly. I need to rebuild the image so I can update the user. My goal is to create the user during run time not build time. It works fine on C7 because I user docker where docker has root access but podman it does not.

Comment: Put amendments into the question, so that others see them (easily).

Comment: Possibly related bug report: https://github.com/containers/fuse-overlayfs/issues/183

Comment: @A.B Possibly those two are related. Thanks for pointing to the ticket :)

Comment: so in short: grab a new RHEL 8.2 kernel and the bug is fixed

Comment: @A.B I will give it a try and I will update the ticket. Thanks again it helped me a lot :)